# SOLR : get data from specific entity

Tags: solr

I have multiple entities having the same field name i.e name

now i want while running http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?q=name:Ch*&wt=json

data only from a particular entity, right now getting data from all entities

is there any way to do this ......

```
 <dataConfig>
 <dataSource name="fds" encoding="UTF-8" baseUrl="file://localhost/tmp/test/"  type="URLDataSource" />
    <document>

 <entity name="tags"
                processor="LineEntityProcessor"
                dataSource="fds"
                url="tags.csv"
                rootEntity="true"
                transformer="RegexTransformer" >
          <field column="rawLine"
                 regex="^(.*),(.*),(.*)$"
                 groupNames="id,name," />
        </entity>
           <entity name="status"
                processor="LineEntityProcessor"
                dataSource="fds"
                url="status.csv"
                rootEntity="true"
                transformer="RegexTransformer" >
          <field column="rawLine"
                 regex="^(.*),(.*),(.*)$"
                 groupNames=",name," />

        </entity>
```

Comment: hm, could you please update question to be more clear?

Comment: @Mysterion I want to get data from one entity only , while running select query, example filter on basis of entity name

Comment: it confuse me a bit, you want to run usual search query and get entity, right?

Comment: ok ....i have two entities status and tags , referring two to different csv files .....both have same field name i.e name now i have a scenario search on name only on entity <<tags>> name but when i am hitting   http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?q=name:Ch*&wt=json          it giving me names from both entity , but i want only from tags